# User authorization in Python Social Auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I can build Facebook login with Python Social Auth. But in order to access full content of the site I want users to be authorised first. Would it be possible to get guidelines how such solution should be build?

Comment: can you clarify your question? I mean, if you can do authentication, you can find out whether users are authenticated or not. So you can do anything you want on your page, e.g. using a simple "if authenticated". So it's not clear what your problem really is.

Comment: Let's say we are running public speaking club and we have our site. Users can be authenticated with facebook for example. But nether-the-less I don't know if those users are members or just guests. I want to verify if he/she is our public speaking club member and only in that case I want to authorise that user for viewing full site content. Hope it helps.

Comment: so you have an "offline" list of members and need to check their names against their facebook names?

Comment: Yes. I have offline list of members. How to check those names is probably another question. The main question here is that even some users are authenticated those still need to be additionally authorized.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the @login_required decorator

Comment: It is true. I can still use @login_required. But it doesn't provide a solution to my need.